# Using invoke on multiple methods with varying amounts of parameters

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have this class full of methods with annotations:

```
@Test(value="checkLoginCredentials")
public void checkLogin(String username, String password) {
    System.out.println("checkLogin has been called with " + username + " and " + password);
}

@Test(value="testOneFunctionality")
public void testOne() {
    System.out.println("testOne has been called, and we have no parameters.");
}
```

And then I have a driver class that is calling invoke on the methods with the `@Test` annotation:

```
Frame frame = new Frame();
    Method[] methods = frame.getClass().getMethods();

    for (Method m : methods) {
        Test annos = m.getAnnotation(Test.class);
        if (annos != null) {
            try {
                m.invoke(frame, (Object) new String ("uname"), (Object) new String ("pw"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Right now this only prints out the string for checkLogin() and not testOne(), but I don't know how to get both methods to be invoked because they each have a different number of parameters. Any help?

There is no confusion with Reflection here, just a question on design so that invoke will call every method regardless of how many parameters each takes.

Comment: Note that this is a design issue - the reflection is working fine.

Comment: You can't invoke a method that takes no parameters with 2 parameters.

Comment: I understand that, and I know how to invoke the other one so that it's the only one that runs. However, I want to know if I can call one invoke and have both methods run.

Comment: if - else loop comparing method name ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no immediate solution for this. Frameworks that use reflection to call methods like you're attempting to do typically have an `ArgumentResolver`. This object basically is a strategy for generating the parameter that your method requires. You would have to create an `ArgumentResolver` for each type of parameter that the method might possibly take. You would put those in a `List` and get the appropriate one for each parameter type the method takes.

You can get the parameter types of a method by calling [`Method.html#getParameterTypes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterTypes%28%29).

For example, Spring uses an interface called [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) to decide and instantiate an object to pass as an argument to a controller method. Each implementation knows which type of parameter it supports and knows how to create it.

Comment: When you say create an ArgumentResolver for each type of parameter, do you mean I can create one for a String type and it will handle all strings I ever want to pass into a method?

Comment: @febreezey Yes, you could have a `StringArgumentResolver`, but you would have to setup default values for it to produce. You can also put annotations on the parameters to give the `ArgumentResolver` hints.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to inspect the method's [parameter types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterTypes%28%29), then adjust the arguments accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Method.getParameterTypes()` to get the parameters for the method and construct an array of matching parameter values to pass to`invoke`.

Answer (score 0):

Test the number of parameters like this:

```
    for (Method m : methods) {
        int nParams = m.getGenericParameterTypes().length;
        switch(nParams) {
        case 0:
            ...

        }
    }
```